# I can't use drand48() and srand48() in C

Tags: c, dev-c++

I'm having problems compiling a program in C using the function drand48(). I wanted to know if and how I can fix this issue.

I've written a program in C which should generate random numbers and confront them with 5 input numbers. I wanted to use drand48()  (because it's the function our professor wants us to use during our exam) but my ide (Dev C++ 6.3.0) keep telling me:

"[Warning] implicit declaration of function 'srand48'; did you mean 'srand'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]"

even though I've included "stdlib.h". I have tried to do the same on many other ide (from Eclipse to CodeBlocks) and they all print the same error and don't compile the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(){

    srand48(1102003);

    int i, num[5], n, count=0;

    double random[100], ran, t;


    //Input

    printf("Digit 5 numbers\n");

    for(i=0; i<5; i++) {

    scanf("%d", &num[i]);

    }

 //Sequence Generation

    for (n=0; n<100; n++) {

    ran=drand48();

    random[n]=round(ran*100);


    }


    //Value check

    for(n=0; n<100; n++) {

        for (i=0; i<5; i++){

            if (num[i]==random[n]) {

                count+=1;

            }


        }

    }

    printf("You guessed %d numbers\n", count);

    system("PAUSE");


}
```

Comment: `drand48` is a Linux function, not a standard C++ function. I'm not sure if it's available on Windows. Are you using Dev-C++ on the course?

Comment: This is not a matter of the IDE, but a matter of the standard library that commonly comes with the compiler system. Which compiler system does your professor expect you to use?

Comment: My professor gave us a linux virtual machine to work, but when I'm not at home I can't use it on my Surface tablet so I started using Dev-C++ and it worked perfectly until now.

Comment: So you are supposed to use Linux as the underlying OS and a provided compiler system in it. That explains why your local environment behaves differently. -- Your next step would be to research how to use `srand48()` on your system, most probably some flavor of Windows with MinGW as compiler system.

Comment: If this compiler supports C++11 or later, you have access to the [`<random>` header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) which contains much better, more convenient, and 100% standard random number generator functions.  You should convert your code to use them instead.

Comment: If it absolutely necessary to use `srand48()` and `drand48()` then you can use Cygwin. They are included in the `<stdlib.h>` header.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround:

At the too of your projekt (after includes) add the following lines.

```
#if !(_SVID_SOURCE || _XOPEN_SOURCE)
double drand48(void) {
    return rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);
}

long int lrand48(void) {
    return rand();
}

long int mrand48(void) {
    return rand() > RAND_MAX / 2 ? rand() : -rand();
}

void srand48(long int seedval) {
    srand(seedval);
}
#endif
```

These will not provide the same values as the rand48 functions (for the same seed), but will behave the same.

From the linux man page:

> These functions are declared obsolete by SVID 3, which states that rand(3) should be used instead.
> So you may always want to use `rand()` instead.

Comment: Note that [SVID 3 was published in 1989](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_V_Interface_Definition).  "it's the function our professor wants us to use during our exam"?!?!  What's the exam?  Coding Autocad in cuneiform to plan a ziggurat?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Unfortunately some professors or even complete schools or universities teach stuff from the former millennium. :-( You can see especially sad examples by the many questions regarding Turbo-C here on SO.

Comment: While this might be a helpful answer in a pinch it’s not necessary because the OP can use Cygwin to access these functions. In addition the functions as written, among other things, do not use 48-bit arithmetic so the naming is misleading.